# Gather the number of customer by street

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables :

Customer:

| id | name | address_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 4 |
| 2 | Kate | 5 |
| 3 | Bob | 2 |
| 4 | Michael | 2 |
| 5 | Adriana | 3 |
| 6 | Ann | 1 |

Address:

| id | detail_str_name | city | district | street_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | France,Paris,str.2,N5 | Paris | Paris | str.2 |
| 2 | France,Parise,str.2 ,N3 | Paris | Paris | str.2 |
| 3 | France, Lille ,str.3,N4 | Lille | Lille | str.3 |
| 4 | France,Paris,str.4,N3 | Paris | Paris | str.4 |
| 5 | France, Paris, Batignolles,N4 | Paris | Batignolles | Batignolles |

I want table like this:

| name | detail_str_name | city | district | street_name | sum(cu.num_cust) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | France,Paris,str.4,N3 | Paris | Paris | str.4 | 1 |
| Kate | France, Paris, Batignolles,N4 | Paris | Batignolles | Batignolles | 1 |
| Bob | France,Parise,str.2 ,N3 | Paris | Paris | str.2 | 3 |
| Michael | France,Parise,str.2 ,N3 | Paris | Paris | str.2 | 3 |
| Adriana | France, Lille ,str.3,N4 | Lille | Lille | str.3 | 1 |
| Ann | France,Paris,str.2,N5 | Paris | Paris | str.2 | 3 |

I want to count customer group by city,district and street_name, not detail_str_name.

I try:

```
        select cu..name,ad.detail_str_name, ad.city,ad.district, ad.street_name,sum(cu.num_cust)
        from
           (select address_id, name,count (id) as num_cust
           from customer
           group by address_id,name) cu
        left join address ad on cu.address_id = ad.id
        group by cu..name,ad.detail_str_name, ad.city,ad.district, ad.street_name
```

But,this code  groups by detail_str_name,
Which does not suit me.

What can I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been able to check this so it might not be totally correct but I think the query below should get the data you require.

This [SQLTutorial article](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-window-functions/sql-partition-by/) on the partition by clause might be useful.

```
SELECT cu.name,
    ad.detail_str_name,
    ad.city,
    ad.district,
    ad.street_name,
    COUNT(cu.name) OVER(PARTITION BY ad.city, ad.district, ad.street_name) AS 'num_cust'
FROM customer cu
JOIN address ad ON ad.id = cu.address_id
```